# Lightweight approach to Materialize Statically Typed Objects

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, data-binding, orm

I inherited an ASP.NET application with an SQL Server backend that initially passed DataSets around a lot. I've been refactoring the code for quite awhile so it's now mostly passing around statically typed objects.

I'm currently using Enterprise Library's ExecuteSprocAccessor to Materialize my objects. I actually find it to be a rather clean and elegant solution but we'll eventually have hundreds of sites with each site running an instance of the code and I'm thinking Enterprise Library is an awfully heavy solution when I just need to materialize objects.

I've generally stayed away from ORMs because I find they get in my way when I try to do non-standard things and I'd rather have more control over the code rather than generating thousands of lines of code that's managed by an ORM. And the data model will be changing quite a bit as I continue to clean things up.

I'm intrigued by Micro-ORMs but wasn't a fan of the syntax of Dapper and didn't like that Massive isn't statically typed.

So, I'm looking for suggestions for a good lightweight solution.

Comment: PetaPoco is looking like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PetaPoco is an ideal solution. The integration with T4 Templates makes it very quick to pull in the data structure through Visual Studio. It's a fast, lightweight, and flexible solution.